# Change intent extras for back navigation intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, activity-stack

I have an app with the following flow (all activities in the same app):

- Activity A starts activity B with `startActivity`. It may add a boolean "autoContinue"=true extra.
- When activity B starts, it checks the "autoContinue" flag in `onCreate` with `getIntent().hasExtra("autoContinue")`. If the flag is true, it immediately starts activity C with `startActivity`.

Now I have two scenarios for pressing the back button in activity C:

- If activity B is still in the activity stack and was not destroyed, everything is fine. Activity C closes and activity B comes into view.
- If I leave activity C by pressing the home button and do some other things before returning to activity C, activity B is often destroyed. Now when I press the back button in activity C, activity B will be created with the Intent that has "autoContinue"=true and immediately start activity C again.

I tried removing the flag from the Intent in activity B's `onCreate`, but it doesn't work:

```
final Intent intent = getIntent();
final Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
if (extras.containsKey("autoContinue")) {
    intent.removeExtra("autoContinue");
    continue();
}
```

How can I remove the "autoContinue"=true flag from the intent extras when navigating back from activity C?

Answer (score 4):

You're on the right track in removing the extra from the intent. However the `Intent` associated with the `Activity` still has the extra in it. You need to call `setIntent()` after removing the extra. So your code will look like this:

```
final Intent intent = getIntent();
final Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
if (extras.containsKey("autoContinue")) {
    intent.removeExtra("autoContinue");
    setIntent(intent);
    continue();
}
```

Comment: `setIntent` isn't doing anything here, you've just passed back the same reference

Answer (score -1):

You can pass extras to previous activity while finishing if you have started the activity with `startActivityForResult` method. See the following code example:

```
public void finishActivity() {
        Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
        returnIntent.putExtra("KEY", "Value");
        getActivity().setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
        getActivity().finish();    
}
```

Also, I want to recommend you not hard code the keys. [Read the blog post that I have written on this topic.](http://sumatodev.com/best-way-to-pass-data-between-android-activities-and-fragments/)